# R RJDBC java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: r, memory, heap-memory, rjdbc

I got following error while run dbGetQuery of RJDBC 0.2-4:

```
Error in .jcall(rp, "I", "fetch", stride) :    
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Following is my code:

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_25')
options(java.parameters='-Xmx1g')
library(rJava)
library(rjson)
library(RJDBC)

# Output Java version
.jinit()
print(.jcall("java/lang/System", "S", "getProperty", "java.version"))

jdbcDriver <<- JDBC(driverClass="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", classPath="C:/lib/dashboard_lib/ojdbc6.jar")
jdbcConnection <<- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "...", "...", "...")
dataset <<- dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, "select * from OPR_DATA.MV_REG_CTRY_MS_QUARTER_AMT")
```

Can anyone help me with this, thanks very much in advance

Comment: Have you tired to make increase the memory to 4g instead of 1g. I mean set options for the java parameters to be `-Xmx4g` instead of `-Xmx1g`

Answer (score 21):

Simply change the java.parameters to 8GB before load RJDBC package:

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8048m")
library("RJDBC")
```

Answer (score 5):

It would fail for me using:

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8048m")
library("RJDBC")
```

However,

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8g")
library("RJDBC")
```

worked.

Answer (score 4):

You can increase the memory as below and restart your Rstudio and it worked for me.

```
memory.limit(size=10000000000024)
```

Answer (score 0):

Commenting in case anyone else comes across this thread with the same error. Updating RJDBC (install.packages("RJDBC")) worked for me.